# Linux CentOs Restart Services

Tags: linux, service, centos, cron

I have some applications running on a remote CentOs server. I'd want them to restart in case of any unexpected server failures or shutdown or application crashes. Any suggestions on how could i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make them "respawn" in inittab. Init can maintain some processes as constantly running. Just set the process you need to continually run to have the action field type of "respawn".

See [here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_inittab.htm).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. let me try it.